# Plot function f(x) vs first three terms of fourier expansion

Tags: plotting, series-expansion, fourier-analysis

I have a function f(x):

```
f[x_] := Sum[(2*(2-2Cos[n*[Pi]]-n*[Pi]Sin[n*[Pi]])/(n^(3)*[Pi]^3))*Sin[n*[Pi]*x]]
```

I want to plot this function vs. the sum of the first three terms (n from 1 to 3) of this function.

So far I've played around with this code:

```
f[k_, n_] := Sum[(2*(2-2Cos[n*[Pi]]-n*[Pi]Sin[n*[Pi]])/(n^(3)*[Pi]^3))*Sin[n*[Pi]*x], {x,1,k}]
partialsums = Table[f[k, n], {k, 1, 3}]
Plot[Evaluate[partialsums], {n, 0, 3}]
```

And I am getting this plot but I am confused of what each line is for? I was hoping to just have one line showing how the function changes with each addition?

[image]

Comment: You have syntax issues in both _Mathematica_ code snippets, can you fix that and share the function you want to plot as an equation, and not a snippet.

Answer (score 2):

I am confused about the math itself you are doing. In F.S. You do not sum over `x` itself, but over the `n`.

Here is an example, may be you can adjust this to your actual $f(x)$

If you want to approximate say $-x$ defined over $-\pi<x<\pi$ then

```
f[x_] := Piecewise[{{-x, -Pi < x < Pi}, {0, True}}]; 
fApprox[x_, maxN_] := 2 Sum[(-1)^n/n Sin[n x], {n, 1, maxN}]; (*This is F.S. of f(x)*)

Plot[{f[x], Evaluate@Table[fApprox[x, n], {n, 1, 3}]}, {x, -Pi, Pi}, 
 PlotLegends -> Flatten@{"f(x)", Range[1, 4]}]
```

[image]

Or you can just use Manipulate and see the effect of adding each term

[image]

```
padIt2[v_, f_List] := 
  AccountingForm[v, f, NumberSigns -> {"", ""}, 
   NumberPadding -> {" ", " "}, SignPadding -> True];
u[x_, max_] := 2 Sum[(-1)^n/n Sin[n x], {n, 1, max}];
f[x_] := -x;
Manipulate[
 Grid[{{Row[{"number of terms ", padIt2[n, {2, 0}]}]}, {Plot[{f[x], 
      Evaluate[u[x, n]]}, {x, -Pi, Pi}, Exclusions -> None, 
     AxesLabel -> {"x", "f(x)"}, BaseStyle -> 15, ImageMargins -> 5, 
     PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
     PlotRange -> {{-Pi, Pi}, {-1.2 Pi, 1.2 Pi}}, 
     GridLines -> Automatic, GridLinesStyle -> LightGray, 
     PlotStyle -> {{Dashed, Blue}, Red}, ImageSize -> 400]}}], 
     {{n, 0,"N"}, 0, 40, 1}, 
    TrackedSymbols :> {n}]
```